# Devise Confirmable emails are not being sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sendgrid, devise-confirmable

Devise account confirmation emails are not being sent out despite heroku logs saying that it is.

I have added the send grid  add-on to my heroku app. I have tried adding config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true to my production.rb file and setting config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true. But none of these seem to work.

config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'math-scientist.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.mailer_sender = 'noreply@mathscientist.com'
  config.reconfirmable = false
```

User Model:

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  end
```

Database Migration:

```
  class AddConfirmableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def up
     add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
      add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
      add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
      add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
      User.update_all confirmed_at: DateTime.now
    end

    def down
      remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at,           
                     :confirmation_sent_at
    end
  end
```

Heroku Logs:

```
  Sent mail to mathscientistofficial@gmail.com (1210.8ms)
  Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 15:51:18 +0000
  From: noreply@mathscientist.com
  Reply-To: noreply@mathscientist.com
  To: mathscientistofficial@gmail.com

  Subject: Confirmation instructions


  <p>Welcome mathscientistofficial@gmail.com!</p>

  <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

  <p><a href="http://math-scientist.herokuapp.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=sSbZLC3ytX8dEc2Xv1e2">Confirm my account</a></p>
```

Edit:
I checked my sendgrid dashboard on heroku and it says that it has received no email requests.

Edit 2:
Heroku has set a send grid username and password for me when I added the send grid add-on. But I do not have a send grid api key. Is it needed to send devise confirmation emails?

Comment: The first question is if SendGrid is receiving the API calls.

Comment: @tadman. How do I check if Sendgrid is receiving the API calls?

Comment: That's a question for the SendGrid dashboard, documentation and/or support department. I'd check that your credentials are correct, like test using something other than this code to verify, and rule out possible failures that way.

Comment: Did you configure your environment variables on heroku?